# How do I fix bumps in carpet that only appear when it's warm and humid?

Tags: flooring

We put all new carpeting in our church worship area in 2007.  The church is on a floating slab and in the summer when the humdity comes, we get serious bumps in the carpet. Some can be as long as three feet while many are five to six inches.  As the weather cools in the fall the bumps disappear.  In the meantime we have bumps that are a threat for tripping our members as they move through the sanctuary.  The carpetlayer used a glue that is suppose to make removal of the carpet "easier" when it comes time to remove.

How do we go about getting rid of these bumps?  Is it feasible to shoot glue with a needle in the carpet and then try and roll the bump out?

Comment: I'll let an expert speak for a real answer, but look into carpet stretching. I don't think glue will do much.

Comment: I don't think you can stretch carpet that is glued down.

Comment: It shouldn't be glued down.  Never do that.

Answer (score 1):

You need a building campaign for A/C and the operating funds to run it.

To verify that as a solution, rent commercial water damage dehumidifiers for a few weeks, and see if you can reduce the bumps.

Something like [MovinCool](http://etopp.com/dehumidifiers.html?gclid=CI7phIqlsrgCFZA-MgodgAMAOA) might do the trick.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Anything like that. Shooting glue has been tried it can work. On larger ones cutting some carpet with one straight cut then folding it back glue it then re-seam the smaller cut glue the seam with seam glue. Find a wet set carpet glue that allows for both ideas. You risk a blemish but at least it's not a tripping hazzard